# CI/CD from Azure Deployment Center failing because repo name must be lower case

Tags: azure, github, github-actions, azure-container-registry

I had an App Service configured 6 months ago with GitHub CI/CD and it was working fine.  Logged into it to find this new deployment center and having to use github actions - so I figured that, and it generated a an action with a yaml file.  But it's failing with the error

```
buildx failed with: error: invalid tag "waldopickem.azurecr.io/***/reactpickem:4fed0719c66061876de0d28cc1bd460b0b818275": repository name must be lowercase
```

I've tried renaming my github repo to lower case it....but I can't rename App Services (and my app service is camel case).

This seems quite basic.  How do I get this unblocked?  I don't know yaml but basic searches didn't turn up an easy solution.

Please help - ci/cd used to work.  Now Azure changed to add new features (which I don't care about) and I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The term "repository" is overloaded. It's not talking about the *code* repository, but rather the *container* repository -- the thing that's being replaced with `***` in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Rename whatever is in the *** to an environment variable `waldopickem.azurecr.io/***/reactpickem:4fed0719c66061876de0d28cc1bd460b0b818275"`

For example, you might have: `waldopickem.azurecr.io/${{secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerUsername}}/reactpickem:4fed0719c66061876de0d28cc1bd460b0b818275"`

change it to:
`waldopickem.azurecr.io/my-repo-name/reactpickem:4fed0719c66061876de0d28cc1bd460b0b818275"`

or

just remove it altogether so that reactpickem becomes the repo name like
`waldopickem.azurecr.io/reactpickem:4fed0719c66061876de0d28cc1bd460b0b818275"`